# Flutter video player quality control for hls videos

Tags: flutter, dart, http-live-streaming, video-player

I am developing a video player app using flutter. In this app, there will be a section for video streaming(HLS). I am using video_player package of Flutter for it, but there is no option to change the quality(1080p, 720p, 240p etc.). How can I implement video quality selection in video_player package?

Comment: Mufeeda Ck could you find any solutions?